# Jaxrs QueryParam as a sub or a root item

Tags: jboss, jax-rs

Hi the design document I'm working off of wants me to have a URL in the pattern of

```
<root>/v1/installs/XYZ123/actions/next?app=1234ABCD HTTP/1.1
```

However the only examples I can find are extremely simple, and only show URLs that would end at the /next.
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/
I'm thinking it's something like... ? I'm missing a key step

```
@GET
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Path("v1/installs/{id}/actions<SOMETHINGHERE?>/next HTTP/1.1")
public Response getSetupCommands(@PathParam("id") 
       String id,@QueryParam("next") String next) {
```

I'm using jboss and jaxrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do I get the feeling that `HTTP/1.1` should *not* be a part of the URL. You may have read/understood the design document incorrectly. If it was saying that the request should look like

```
GET /v1/installs/XYZ123/actions/next?app=1234ABCD HTTP/1.1
```

Then you only need to be worried about `/v1/installs/XYZ123/actions/next?app=1234ABCD`. `HTTP/1.1` is simply the HTTP version that will be used implicitly with every request and response.

Your original example was fine, exception you should have replaced `@QueryParam("next")` with `@QueryParam("app")`. `next` is actually part of the path.

This `/v1/installs/{id}/actions/next` should be what's included in `@Path`.

The complete semantics of this request URL seems to read something like:

Get the `next` (resource) controller, and we will use the `app` query parameter as an argument to pass to this controller.

---

### UPDATE: with example

```
@Path("/v1")
public class QueryResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/installs/{id}/actions/next")
    public Response getResponse(@PathParam("id") String id, 
                                @QueryParam("app") String app) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("ID: ").append(id).append("<br/>");
        sb.append("app param: ").append(app);
        return Response.ok(sb.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

Browser Test

[image]

Fire bug

[image]

Comment: Hmmm.. If you are correct I might have to have a talking to with my coworker about their poor documentation skills. It's not obvious to us android developers, 3 of my coworkers read it the same as I did :-/

Comment: Says a lot about my job if I just assumed the engineer did a massive hack / completely backwards design, than I might have misunderstood the documentation.. Or the fact I had no power or input when I came across the massive hack.

Comment: Yea, when you send an HTTP request, the first line of the request will be `GET /bla/blah/next?app=1234ABCD HTTP/1.1`. `GET` is the method, next is the URL, next is the HTTP version. The version is implicitly applied, but it is not part of the URL.

Comment: Yes I realized I was incorrect when I got up this morning. Removing the http/1.1 allows you to get the query string, and everything works. I got mixed up last night. Don't select answers when tiered! :-) I was forgetting to add the code to read the query string back in.

Comment: Thanks for the super detailed examples. I wish I could give you more points. I'm more than sure it will get a few stars in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
v1/installs/{id}/actions/{next : .+}
public Response getSetupCommands(@PathParam("id") String id,@PathParam("next") String next) {
```

Way too hackish for my tastes, but I don't have any control in this situation..

Comment: This is the correct answer. While peeskillet is right about the documenatation stuff, the issue is the question mark.

Comment: The question mark is added implicitly to the URL when we use query parameters. We need _not_ worry about that with JAX-RS. The URL will be parsed, and everything after the `?` will become query parameters available through `@QueryParam`. The way you are are doing is a _horrible_ way to handle query Strings

Comment: Even the mkyong tutorial you linked to uses the `@QueryParam`. Maybe you didn't understand the tutorial correctly :-)

Comment: Let me rephrase _"The question mark is added implicitly to the URL"_. When using forms and GET, the `?` will be implicitly added. But The semantics of the `?` is just a separator between the _path_ and _query string_. Read more about [Query Strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)